Make customised list of figures
I am supposed to make a compliance report and have to submit a lot of documents as images within the document along with hyperlinks in the first page .I have been using word for a long time and now trying to use latex to automate this process .I nearly automated everything but stuck on the Front page which navigates the person to page where the image of the document is present .Since I am fairly new and spend lot of time trying hyperlink,list of figures is there a simple way to do this. 
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[font=Large,labelfont=bf,labelformat=empty]{caption}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{} % uppercase title
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\large\bfseries} % bold 14pt
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\par\protect\mbox{}\protect\hrulefill\par} % horizontal line 
\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0pt} % left aligned fig entries
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{} % put before the number
\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{1.5em} % extra space for \cftpresnum
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
    pdftitle={322},
    pdfpagemode=,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
        \textbf{\Huge{Criteria 3- Research, Innovations and Extension \\}\vspace{5 mm}
            \LARGE{Key Indicator -3.2- Innovation Ecosystem}}\\
        \vspace{5 mm}
        \textbf{\Large{3.2.2 Number of workshops/seminars conducted on Research Methodology, Intellectual Property Rights (IPR) and entrepreneurship during the year}}
    \end{center}
    \listoffigures
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \caption{Web Verse 2023 }
        \includegraphics[width=1 \linewidth,height=1.5\linewidth]`{img01/01-1.jpg}
        \label{01-1}
    \end{figure}
\begin{figure}
        \centering
        \caption{Web Verse 2023 }
        \includegraphics[width=1 \linewidth,height=1.5\linewidth]`{img01/01-2.jpg}
        \label{01-1}
    \end{figure}
\begin{figure}
        \centering
        \caption{Web Verse 2023 }
        \includegraphics[width=1 \linewidth,height=1.5\linewidth]`{img01/01-3.jpg}
        \label{01-1}
    \end{figure}
    \clearpage

\end{document}

This now ended up with something like this 

Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show a short compilable TeX code you have so far, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Welcome. // Right. We need to have at least an idea of what you've been doing. E.g. did you use package pdfpages (https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages), or did you create one image per page somehow? // Some fake code, which compiles, AND shows your approach will be useful. Thank you

pdfpages is wonderfull and something that will reduce my time.I was converting the pdf pages to images and then inserting using \includegraphics.

off-topic: fontsize commands in latex such as \LARGE don't take arguments. they just switch the size until further notice. also, why do you have backticks in the middle of your \includegraphics commands? that doesn't look correct at all.

consider using \title{Key-Indicator ...} and \maketitle rather than hard-coding appearance.
